# Does left-invertible imply invertible in full group C*-algebras (discrete case)?

Tags: c-star-algebras, oa.operator-algebras

The following question/problem has been bugging me on and off for some time now: so I thought it might be worth broaching here on MO, as a case of "ask the experts".

Let $G$ be a discrete group. Kaplansky observed that since the group von Neumann algebra $VN(G)$ is a finite von Neumann algebra, each left-invertible element in $VN(G)$ is invertible. A proof is outlined in

> M.S. Montgomery, Left and right inverses in group algebras, Bull. AMS 75 (1969)

(Well, she actually states a weaker result, but inspection shows that her argument extends to give what we claim. See also my remarks on this [previous MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18508/is-a-left-invertible-element-of-a-group-ring-also-right-invertible/18509#18509).)
The basic idea is to exploit the **faithful** trace $T\mapsto \langle T\delta_e,\delta_e\rangle$ and how it behaves on idempotents: for if $ab=I$, then $ba$ is an idempotent.

In particular, each left-invertible element of the reduced group $C^*$-algebra is invertible.

**Question.** What can we say for the **full** group $C^*$-algebra? Is every left-invertible element in $C^*(G)$ automatically invertible?

Some basic observations:

- The case where $G$ is the free group on two generators follows from a result of M-D Choi [no relation] who showed that $C^*({\mathbb F}_2)$ embeds into a direct product of matrix algebras.
- More generally, if $C^*(G)$ has a faithful trace then one can use the same argument as for the reduced $C^*$-algebra to get a positive answer.
- If $C^*(G)$ has no non-trivial projections then $ab=I$ implies $ba=I$. (I think this was known to be true for $G={\mathbb F}_2$ but I've forgotten the reference at present.)
- There are examples of $G$ where $C^*(G)$ has no faithful trace; these can be found in work of Bekka and Louvet, and come from exploiting Property (T).

> Bekka, M. B.(F-METZ-MM); Louvet, N.(CH-NCH)
>   Some properties of $C^*$-algebras associated to discrete linear groups. $C^*-algebras (Münster, 1999), 1–22, Springer, Berlin, 2000.

Comment: Would Bill Johnson know? There is an ask-johnson tag. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ask-johnson 

Comment: @Will: I think of WBJ as more of a Banach-space specialist than an operator algebraist, but it is entirely possible he might spot something I haven't here.

Comment: I printed out your arXiv piece 1003.1650v2. Very nice.

Comment: Just a remark: if a $C^*$-algebra $A$ does not have tracial states then $A^{**}$ has an isometry which is not unitary, thus $A^{**}$ does not satisfy Kaplanski condition. Little bit more is true: for every $n$ there are $n$ pairwise orthogonal isometries in $A^{**}$. 

Comment: Nice question, and I do not know the answer. In fact, Yemon would be hard pressed to ask a question about operator algebras to which I know the answer but he does not.

Comment: I fear Bill is either flattering me or being excessively modest. (I'm at heart a dilettante when it comes to operator algebras.) The sentiment is appreciated, though.

Answer (score 15):

That's a nice question.  I don't know the answer for arbitrary groups, but this finiteness property (left invertible implies invertible in the full group C*-algebra) is known for more groups.  M.D. Choi's result was generalized by [Exel and Loring, Internat. J. Math. 1992].  We say that a C*-algebra if residually finite dimensional (RFD) if it has a separating family of finite dimensional representations.  RFD algebras have this finiteness property and finite groups, abelian groups, etc., have RFD full group C*-algebras. Exel and Loring show that unital full free products of RFD C*-algebras are RFD.  So if $C^*(G_i)$ are RFD (i=1,2), then so is $C^*(G_1*G_2)$.   A broader class of C*-algebras than the RFD ones are the MF algebras of [Blackadar and Kirchberg, Math. Ann., 1997].  In MF algebras, all left invertibles are invertible.  Recently, [Hadwin, Q. Li, J. Shen, Canad. J. Math. 2011] showed that unital full free products of MF C*-algebras are MF.

Comment: Thanks for the references - I will have to set aside some time to read up on these results.

Answer (score 8):

There is an alternative argument for the free group; not using that free groups are residually finite-dimensional.

Let $\pi$ be a faithful representation of $C^{\ast}(F)$ on a Hilbert space $H$. Then, as $U(H)$ is connected, $\pi$ can be deformed to the trivial representation in the point-norm topology, i.e. there exists a family of unitary representations $\pi_t$ for $t \in [0,1]$, such that $t \mapsto \pi_t(a)$ is norm-continuous for each $a \in C^{\ast}(F)$, $\pi_0=\pi$ and $\pi_1(g)=1_H$ for all$ g \in F$.

Now, if $ab=1$ in $C^{\ast}(F)$, then $\pi_t(ba)$ is a continuous path of projections ending at $1_H$. Hence, $\pi_0(ba)=1_H$ and $ba=1$, as $\pi$ was faithful.

**EDIT:** The same argument works if the $C^{\ast}$-algebra embeds into some contractible algebra (i.e. homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb C$). However, even though many reasonable toplogical spaces are quotients of contractible topological spaces, only few reasonable $C^{\ast}$-algebras have this property. There is a close relationship with the concept of quasi-diagonality, which appeared in the work of Voiculescu.

Comment: I don't quite follow-- is the point about why this works for a _free_ group that I can take a path through the unitaries for each generator, and then let these (uniquely) induce my *-rep of C^*(F)-- that we have no relations to worry about means that this always works??

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Reading your answer it reminded me that I'd seen a similar outline before - I guess this kind of argument is very natural for those who've looked at K-theory of group (C*-)algebras. After doing some looking, it seems that this kind of argument was used by J. Cohen in http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=546507

Comment: Matthew, you are absolutely right.