# Finitely presentable group with purely infinite full group $C^*$-algebra?

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, geometric-group-theory

Does there exist an example of a finitely presentable group whose full group $C^*$-algebra is purely infinite,
resp. is it known to be impossible?

Comment: Each full group C*-algebra of a discrete group has a character (the trivial one) and therefore can't be purely infinite

Comment: Right, that even applies to any representation for the group, so also the C*-algebra generated by any such representation. That answers my question to the full extent. Thank you Caleb Eckhardt!

Comment: Perhaps, it's more interesting to ask whether full group C*-algebras are (stably) finite.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78948/does-left-invertible-imply-invertible-in-full-group-c-algebras-discrete-case/79008

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: Yes that might be more interesting. For explanation: the intent of the question was to find quotients $C^*(Z/2*...Z/2)=\mathbb{C}^n*_1\ldots*_1\mathbb{C}^n\to Q$ that have no tracial states left $TQ=\varnothing$ and which are themselves game algebras (of non-local games) so only quotients of the form $pq=0$ for pairs of spectral projections of generators $p=e_{ax}$ and $q=e_{by}$, and so I thought of perhaps to look into purely infinite subalgebras of full group algebras $Q=C^*(\Gamma LCS)$ to rule them out, but any group algebras are of course impossible.